# How to set datum in GPS connection setup window in ArcFM Viewer for ArcGIS Engine Application

Tags: gps, arcgis-engine, datum, arcfm

I have a custom application based on ArcFM Viewer for ArcGIS Engine. I want to use an external GPS receiver with that application and the setup window does not let me choose a different geographic datum. In comparison the corresponding drop down field in ArcGIS Desktop has a variety of datums to choose from. Where is this list defined? How can I get this in my ArcFM Viewer application? It might also be helpful to know where ArcGIS actually gets that list from. Here are some screenshots. Sorry for the German UI.

ArcFM Viewer:

[image]

ArcGIS Desktop:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This should answer your question:

https://infrastructurecommunity.schneider-electric.com/docs/DOC-7197